# How to show math equation in php / HTML?

Tags: php, html, math, mathml

I have a ckeditor where we can create math equation when I am fetch equation from database it look like `a+b2` but I want like `(a+b)^2`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

```
html_entity_decode($post->answer)
```

I am using `html_entity_decode` but it not look exactly I want.

Comment: So the `^` is missing? Is it actually stored in the database or not?

Comment: No Sir, Actually its look like `<p>&nbsp;<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><msup><mfenced><mrow><mi>a</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi></mrow></mfenced><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>=</mo><msup><mi>a</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>+</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi></mrow></math></p>
` it is in my database.

Comment: Thanks, but if you have extra info, please use the "edit" button under your question to add it to your main post, then it's clearly visible to everyone and can be formatted clearly, plus you have space to add enough relevant detail. Also I added the MathML tag to your question since it appears to be relevant.

Comment: Anyway, if the data isn't there in the database to begin with, then you need to trace back through the code which inputs and then saves the data into the database. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please, then we can trace this through your code properly, rather than just seeing a single line completely out of context. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Browser support for MathML](https://caniuse.com/mathml) is still rather patchy, but you can get it working in just about any browser by adding the MathJax library to your web document. Just add the following two lines to your HTML:

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

It should then render correctly. Try running the following snippet for example:

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<p>&nbsp;<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><msup><mfenced><mrow><mi>a</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi></mrow></mfenced><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>=</mo><msup><mi>a</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>+</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi></mrow></math></p>
```

Comment: Thank for the reply sir but I try it with `<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
  </script>` and it work perfectly

Comment: Yes, that's fine too. The polyfill script just adds compatibility for a few more browsers.